# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBounds error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class s
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        String string=input.next();
        System.out.println(string.charAt(7));
    }
}
```

I get this error when i run the program and i don't understand why. All i want to do is print the 7th character.

```
PS E:\Users\adiad\Documents\Scuola\Informatica\Madeo\Pratica> java s
hello world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at s.main(s.java:9)
```

Comment: `Scuola\Informatica`... you could make it less obvious it's your homework ;)

Comment: @NickSlavsky there's nothing wrong with [asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) per se. In this case, it's a simple thing that OP doesn't understand, and it would be cruel to leave him thrashing around not being able to make progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `next()`, which only reads the `hello` the first time you call it. You would get the `world` if you called `next()` again.

Use `nextLine()` if you want to read `hello world` in one go.

You can refer [to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) to read more about the different methods available on the `Scanner` class.

Comment: Thanks so much! Our teacher didn't actually explained us the meaning of next()

Comment: @Adam hopefully s/he has told you about Javadoc, though.